# Bash profile alias error

Tags: bash, macos, alias

In my bash profile I want to create an alias to go to the iBook folder directly which is buried deep inside. So I wrote this
`alias ibook= 'cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books'` . But I am getting this error message: `-bash: alias: cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books: not found` . I have checked the path, it is okay. What is going wrong here?

Comment: @EricRenouf As I didn't know the error while asking the question, so it was not a duplicate question. But I think the question you pointed to do provide a broader perspective.

Comment: A duplicate isn't a bad thing, it's just a way to mark that another way of asking the question was found, but that they're really the same problem.  Other people might find it the way you ask it and also benefit from seeing the answer(s) in the related question

Comment: @EricRenouf Oh, okay. Thank you for the clarification. And thanks for the link to other question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the space after the equals sign:

```
alias ibook='cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books'
```

Comment: :P . Thank you! It is working now.